# How can I get the status of my child element in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know how I can get the status of my child element in this situation please

```
class Child extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            element : "I NEED THIS STATE"
        }

    }

    render(){
        return <h1>Hello</h1>
    }
}

class Main extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Child />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate why you need this. What are you are trying to achieve overall?

Answer (score 3):

Simply make it work, you can do it the way @Andrew suggests. However, i strongly **discourage** you from doing this unless you are really aware of what you're doing.

React encourages *uni-directional data flow* to help make your code easier to reason about. A rule of thumb approach can be simplified as ***props down, events up***.

1. **Data** passes down from parent to child using `props` (*read-only* prevents child from mutating parent's `state` by accident).
2. **Events** bubbles up from children to inform its parent what's happened. (Typically by calling parent passed function/callback `props` in child's event handlers)

In react's component system, both parent and child have **isolated** scopes. This means parent should have no knowledge about its children (including its `state` in your case), and children can only read parent's data through `props`. In order to change state to trigger UI refresh, `this.setState()` is your friend, typically used in event handlers / server request callbacks.

recommended reading: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

<sub>Btw. React's declarative component composition is essentially function composition. Your question is similar to "Can i get the local variables of closure in the function where it's declared", obviously, you can do this, but you have to ask yourself why you're doing this to break the encapsulation.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you and you need your status in main component.

```
class Child extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            element : "I NEED THIS STATE"
        }

    }

    render(){
        this.props.checkStatus(this.state.element);
        return <h1>Hello</h1>
    }
}

class Main extends React.Component{
getChildStatus(status){
    console.log(status)
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Child checkStatus={this.getChildStatus}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

As Felix said, function that we throw with props usually used on some event like onClick or onChange. Something like `return <h1 onClick={this.props.checkStatus(this.state.element)}>Hello</h1>`

Comment: Calling `this.props.checkStatus(this.state.element);` in the `render()` function is a bit weird though.

Comment: @Felix I don't know on which event he can check this status, so i did by this way.

Comment: Or you mean, i should call function in return?

Comment: No. I think it would be worth to explain that the function that is passed to the child is usually called in response to an event.

Comment: It could be a hack to fetch info from children, but will break the encapsulation (aka. the `uni-directional` data flow). The `callback` from parent is **meant** to mutate the `state` of parent on the children side (inversion of control, aka IOC)

Comment: Btw. React's declarative component composition is nothing more than function composition. His question is the same as `Can i get state from closure in the function where it's declared`?